# google cloud sql geometry very slow query

Tags: mysql, performance, google-cloud-sql

I've a shape file (.shp, .shx, .dbf ) that I've loaded in CloudSQL using the tool script below

```
ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:$DB_NAME,host=$HOST,user=$DB_USER,password=$DB_PWD $SHAPE_FILE -progress -nlt POLYGON -nln geo -update -overwrite -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry -lco engine=MYISAM
```

Happens that when I run the queries below on my local environment (official docker image MySQL 5.6) everithing is fast (mseconds) But when I type the same query against the cloudsql instance the performance are very poor (5-7) seconds.

Query example:

```
SELECT count(geometry) from geo where zip='20020'; -- took 9.56s
```

but if I type the same query without the zip clause

```
SELECT count(geometry) from geo; -- took 0.03s
```

The total number of records are: 8959;
I have index on zip column.

Is there something I'm missing or special index?

Below the table created by ogr2ogr

```
CREATE TABLE `geo` (
  `OGR_FID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `geometry` geometry NOT NULL,
  `zip` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `offices` decimal(9,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shape_leng` double(19,11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shape_area` double(19,11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` decimal(9,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `OGR_FID` (`OGR_FID`),
  SPATIAL KEY `geometry` (`geometry`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8960 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What's the type of the `zip` column?

Comment: try COUNT(*) and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @jsn I've tried and is fast (msec)

Comment: `COUNT(x)` has to fetch `x` to see if it is `NULL` (and not count it).  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE geo`.  I suspect that `geometry is elsewhere.

Comment: Ehi guys, thank you. I've solved.. I've have index on the zip column but my query was: SELECT count(geometry) from geo where zip=20020 and not SELECT count(geometry) from geo where zip='20020' since the field is of type varchar. Thanks @Rick James, your suggestion helped me figure out the mistake.